# How to create this line reversed with css correctly

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the line on the left-side in the picture on the right side reversed

*see image below:*

[image]

```css
.line-down {
  width: 50px;
  height: 60px;
  border: solid 5px #9494b8;
  border-color: transparent #9494b8 transparent transparent;
  border-radius: 100%/100px 340px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="line-down"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to flip the right-hand shape on its x-axis:

```css
body{display:flex;justify-content:space-around}

.line-down {
  width: 50px;
  height: 60px;
  border: solid 5px #9494b8;
  border-color: transparent #9494b8 transparent transparent;
  border-radius: 100%/100px 340px 0 0;
}

.line-down.right{
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}
```

```html
<div class="line-down"></div>
<div class="line-down right"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can switch the rules between the left border and the right border and it will be exactly the same shape.

```
.line-down.right {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #9494b8;
  border-radius: 100%/340px 100px 0 0;
}
```